# Ionic 2 app.scss issue

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have been working on an ionic 2 app for a month. I usually test in on Android and it was working perfectly fine. I just ran on IOS, and the design is very wrong. It looks like it is not reading the app.scss file which I use for global CSS classes. Any idea what is the issue ?

This is a sample of the app.scss file

```
/***** Validation *****/
.error {
    background-color: $red;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    color: white;
}

.error ion-icon {
    padding-right: 5px;
}

/***** Loading *****/
ion-spinner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;

    .z-index {
        z-index: 2;
    }
}

/***** Menu *****/
.header-md::after, .tabs-md[tabsPlacement="top"] > .tabbar::after, .footer-md::before, .tabs-md[tabsPlacement="bottom"] > .tabbar::before {
    background-image: none;
}

ion-header {
    .navbar {
        padding: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #aeaeae;
    }

    .navbarSection {
        padding: 8px 8px 0px 8px;
    }

    .menuSection {
        text-align: left;

        button:hover,
        button {
            color: white !important;

            div {
                margin-left: 10px;
            }
        }
    }

    .titleSection {
        text-align: center;

        ion-title h5 {
            font-size: 14px;
            color: white;
        }
    }

    .buttonsSection {
        text-align: right;

        button, button:hover {
            background-color: #ffffff !important;
            color: $black;
            font-weight: bolder;
            text-transform: none;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        ion-icon {
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
    }

    .categoriesSection {
        background-color: white;
        height: 42px;


        .filterSection {
            div {
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .filter-icon {
                color: $blue;
                margin-left: 15px;
                font-weight: bolder;
            }

            .filter-searchbar {
                position: relative;
                margin-left: 10px;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the styles ok when you run the app on the browser with ionic lab?

Comment: yes. I usually work on browser and run on android at the end of the phase. Everything was ok. But on IOS, I guess CSS  classes not working

Comment: can you  add the app.scss file to your question?

Comment: It is around 1000lines. I added a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your styles included in app.scss seem to be android specific.

eg:

```
.header-md::after, .tabs-md[tabsPlacement="top"] > .tabbar::after, .footer-md::before, .tabs-md[tabsPlacement="bottom"] > .tabbar::before {
```

classes with `-md` suffix are set only for android. You will have to set similar styles for `-ios` suffix.

```
.header-ios::after, .tabs-ios[tabsPlacement="top"] > .tabbar::after, .footer-ios::before, .tabs-ios[tabsPlacement="bottom"] > .tabbar::before {
```

Comment: wow didn't noticed that. I guess that will solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: I am fixing it by removing the -md . Is it correct?

Comment: It depends on what kind of view you want in both ios and android.. remember android by default uses material design theme.. so what looks good in android , same style may or may not be suitable for ios. but yeah removing will put it for both